# Getting mule message properties in a Jersey resource component class

Tags: java, rest, mule

I have a REST service flow in Mule:

```
<flow name="rest-service">
    <inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:9099"/>
    <logger message="API request received from #[header:INBOUND:MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS]" level="INFO" />
    <jersey:resources>
        component class="com.example.rest.MyResource"/>
    </jersey:resources>
</flow>
```

I want to get the MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS property inside the component class `MyResource`. I tried implementing `MuleContextAware` but was not able to retrieve message properties from `MuleContext` object.

Any other way to get the message properties? I am using Mule 3.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RequestContext.getEvent()`

See: http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.2.0/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/RequestContext.html